# Material UI Paper background color based on elevation?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a dark-themed React frontend that uses Material guidelines. According to [dark theme specifications](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#properties), surfaces should be lightened with each elevation level. This doesn't seem to work with the `elevation` property in material-ui's Paper component, it seems to only add a shadow. I am wondering if this specification is already implemented, or what the best solution would be for having this effect.

Example:

```
<Paper elevation={1}>
    <Typography variant="h6">Paper1</Typography>
</Paper>
<Paper elevation={5}>
    <Typography variant="h6">Paper2</Typography>
</Paper>
```

This two papers have different elevations, but still have the same background color.

Comment: Can you, please, add code example of what you've done?

Comment: I added some example code, hopefully it is enough to show the issue

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem. Seems like material-ui does implement elevation only by adding the box shadow.
A quick solution I came up with (typescript):

```js
import { lighten, makeStyles, Paper, Theme } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, { elevation: number }>((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    boxShadow: (props) => theme.shadows[props.elevation],
    backgroundColor: (props) =>
      lighten(theme.palette.background.paper, props.elevation * 0.025),
  },
}));


export const CustomPaper: React.FC<{elevation: number}> = ({ children, elevation }) => {
  const classes = useStyles({ elevation });
  return (
    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
      {children}
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

I find that the factor 0.025 produces a decent look. However, I came up with it just by a bit of trial and error. There may be more sophisticated approaches.